# What are the techniques to deal with classifying sparse categorical features?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, sparse

Suppose I have a group of features each one is sparse with a few number of values (1-10) what are the required preprocessing steps required to avoid degradation of the performance of the classifier especially if the number of features is moderate and the data is not very large?

Comment: in general it would be recommended to recategorise into meaningful categories (which will not be sparse) - eg rather than having a list of 100 jobs recategorise into manual/office worker... and use hierarchies etc. basically you probably know a lot about the categories that is not available to the learning algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can use penalized methods like, Lasso (for variable selection) and Elastic Net (for grouping). Look at this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_net_regularization and references within.